# Passing Parameters to facebook callback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have an app written in Asp.Net MVC and Jquery. The app has a functionality to post a message to facebook wall.
When the user clicks the post button on my custom dialog, i do a redirect to

> "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxx&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://localhost:xxxx/Posts/AuthorizeFaceBook&scope=publish_stream"

using Jquery. And once the user completes log in to facebook my callback is getting executed without any issues. But how can i pass my Post message to the call back from the original custom dialog?

Is storing the message string in a Session, is the only to way to access the message from the callback ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think you need to add it to your callback URL.

Comment: Yup, you can pass parameters into the redirect uri or store them in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the parameters in your redirect URL.  You must also uri encode the redirect URL.